# XDEBUG is not working with PHPSTORM

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, xdebug, laravel-5.1

From `phpinfo()` I can see XDEBUG is installed. I am using XAMPP and have configured the php.ini file in XAMPP like below -

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/Applications/XAMPP/tmp"
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

I am trying to run my Laravel project using PHP web application configuration in phpstorm but getting - Waiting for incoming connection with ide key ':random key:'.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your PhpStorm debug configuration?

Comment: The first hint as to what's wrong is that XDEBUG is configured with the key PHPSTORM but the session is waiting for ':random key:'.

Comment: Are you trying to use the 'listen' feature in PhpStorm or did you set up a debug configuration? The latter is the preferred and easier way.